# How to access multiple tables in sqlite3 for iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

In a single database example abc.sqlite has the 4 tables `(cases,questions,category and options).`

Each table has different columns.

How to get the data from table1 column1, table2 column 2.

How to write queries for that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to learn more on `SQL92` the query language for the databases, that let you select and insert data to your tables. Actually the sqlite documentation is one of the best because contains the useful `syntax diagrams` that you find on http://sqlite.com/lang.html